# How to use the <picture> tag in new WordPress Gutenberg editor?

Tags: wordpress

Several months ago I built a blog for a client, and one of the things they demanded was to replace the default WordPress editor image html output for the responsive picture tag.
It took me some time to figure it out but I eventually came up with a decent solution. However, with the next update WordPress will replace the old wysiwyg editor with Gutenberg, which will override my changes and replace them with Gutenberg's html output, which will in turn break the layout of the new posts on the site. I will need to fix this issue quickly after the update but I have no idea how to do it because at the moment I'm not familiar with how Gutenberg works.

This is the function I built in order to replace the default post image html output:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'responsive_insert_image()' ) ) {
    function responsive_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size) {
        $alt_text = get_post_meta($id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        if ( !$alt_text ) { 
            $alt_text = esc_html( get_the_title($post_id) ); 
        }   

        $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');
        $xl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'extra-large');
        $lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'large');
        $md = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'medium'); 
        $sm = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'small');
        $xs = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'thumbnail');                
        $xl_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'extra-large-2x');
        $lg_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'large-2x');
        $md_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'medium-2x'); 
        $sm_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'small-2x');
        $xs_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'thumbnail-2x');

        $attributes  = (!empty($id) ? ' id="attachment_' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '' );
        $class = ' class="' . 'align'.esc_attr($align) . '"';
        if($a_elem != "" || $caption != "") {
            $pic_atts = "";
        } else {
            $pic_atts = $attributes . $class;
        }
        if($caption != "") {
            $link_atts = "img-link";
        } else {
            $link_atts = $attributes . $class;
        }

        $linkptrn = "/<a[^>]*>/";
        $found = preg_match($linkptrn, $html, $a_elem);
        if($found > 0) {
            $a_elem = $a_elem[0];
            if(strstr($a_elem, "class=\"") !== false){ // If link already has class defined inject it to attribute
                $a_elem = str_replace("class=\"", "target=\"_blank\" " . $class . $link_atts . " ", $a_elem);
            } else { // If no class defined, just add class attribute
                $a_elem = str_replace("<a ", "<a " . $class . $attributes . " target=\"_blank\" ", $a_elem);
            }
        } else {
            $a_elem = "";
        }   

        if ($size == 'full') {
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $full[0] . '" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $full[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }
        } elseif ($size == 'extra-large') {
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $xl[0] . ', ' . $xl_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 1200px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $lg[0] . ', ' . $lg_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $md[0] . ', ' . $md_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $sm[0] . ', ' . $sm_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $xs[0] . ', ' . $xs_2x[0] . ' 2x" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }
        } elseif ($size == 'large') {   
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $lg[0] . ', ' . $lg_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $md[0] . ', ' . $md_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $sm[0] . ', ' . $sm_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $xs[0] . ', ' . $xs_2x[0] . ' 2x" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }           
        } elseif ($size == 'medium') {
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $md[0] . ', ' . $md_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $sm[0] . ', ' . $sm_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $xs[0] . ', ' . $xs_2x[0] . ' 2x" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }               
        } elseif ($size == 'small') {
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $sm[0] . ', ' . $sm_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $xs[0] . ', ' . $xs_2x[0] . ' 2x" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }               
        } elseif ($size == 'thumbnail') {
            if ($caption) {
                $html = '<figure' . $attributes .'>';
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            $html .= $a_elem;       
            $html .= '<picture' . $pic_atts .'>';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<source srcset="' . $sm[0] . ', ' . $sm_2x[0] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
            $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
            $html .= '<img srcset="' . $xs[0] . ', ' . $xs_2x[0] . ' 2x" alt="' . $alt_text . '">';
            $html .= '</picture>';
            if($a_elem != "") {
                $html .= '</a>';
            }
            if ($caption) {
                $html .= '<figcaption class="caption wp-caption-text">'.$caption.'</figcaption>';
                $html .= '</figure>';
            }               
        }
        return $html;
    }
    add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'responsive_insert_image', 10, 9 );
    add_filter( 'disable_captions', create_function('$a', 'return true;') );
}
```

Is there a way to modify this function somehow in order to make it compatible with the new Gutenberg editor?

Comment: You could probably provide your own custom override for that default image block. Best to ask this on the gutenberg github repo I think to get an answer right from the people working on the editor.

Comment: You will have a special 'classic' block in which you will be able to include this tag without any problems. https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/faq.md#will-i-be-able-to-opt-out-of-gutenberg-for-my-site